# NestedScrollView not scrolling with viewpager in Cordinatorlayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, android-viewpager2, coordinator-layout

I have a Cordinatorlayout that contains a viewpager , a recyclerview, a tablayout and some other views,,
i want my screen to scroll properly, but it does not.

(the problem is shown in the gif)
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".home.ui.views.HomeFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
            app:toolbarId="@id/toolbar">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">


                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/worksans_regular"
                        android:text="Discover"
                        android:textColor="@color/purple_S600"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button"
                        android:layout_width="26dp"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/white_grey_s400"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/account_icon"
                        android:padding="1dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


            </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_textInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search_edittext_shape"
            android:textColorHint="@color/purple_grey_S600"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
            app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
            app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/close_icon"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:endIconTint="@color/purple_S600"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/search_icon"
            app:startIconTint="@color/purple_S600">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/home_search_tf"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Search"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="0dp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/categories_tabs"
            style="@style/CategoriesTabLayourStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>



    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_constraint"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            >
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:background="@color/yellow_S600"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/worksans_semibold"
                    android:text="Deals      "
                    android:textColor="@color/purple_S600"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="-28dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/deals_arrow"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/inter_regular"
                    android:text="UP to 75% off"
                    android:textColor="@color/purple_S600"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/flame_icon"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/deals_recyclerview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/deal_product" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nested_view" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have tried so many tweaks but it just didn't seem to work.
As a last resort I have tried to put the deals section which is a constraintlayout that contains a couple of views with a horizontal recyclerview. it try to put it inside a NestedScrollView but this does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

This is not answer that you want, but it is suggestion.
You can solve this issue with concat adapter and recyclerview, instead of nested scrollviews.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ConcatAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Avoid nesting the `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView` Instead of using a `NestedScrollView`, you can directly use the `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayoutManager` set to a horizontal orientation. This way, you won't need the extra layer of nesting and can achieve the desired scrolling behavior within the RecyclerView itself. In a `RecyclerView`, it is more easy to handle different types of view types. https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview

The drawbacks when you use a `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView` are described here. [Why am I experiencing ANRs with RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView and what are the recommended alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76339713/why-am-i-experiencing-anrs-with-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview-and-what-ar/76340109#76340109)

In your current code you can fix the scroll issue by adding below flag in `RecyclerView`

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have wrapped the constraint layout with the nestedscrollview. I did it the other way around.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_constraint"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">


            <TextView
                .... />


            <ImageView
                .... />

            <TextView
                .... />

            <ImageView
                ..../>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                .... />



    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        .... />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This the solution, Thanks everyone